# Irrational distance between a certain point and every other point with rational coordinates

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb R^n $, be a Lebesgue measurable set of positive measure.

Show that in $A$ there is a point such that if you consider distances from it to every point in $R^n$ whose coordinates are rational, these distances are irrational.

Comment: For a point $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, what can you say about the set of points whose distance to $p$ is rational?